# Convert Fortran user defined type to C++ class

Tags: c++, fortran, converters

Is there a tool out there to handle this for me? I am using the Intel Fortran compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "convert", but a major feature of [FortWrap](http://fortwrap.sourceforge.net/) is: "The resulting wrapper code provides a C++ interface that wraps the Fortran derived types with C++ proxy classes." So that might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Fable](http://cci.lbl.gov/fable/) as it's quite likely what you're looking for.

Comment: It is very obsolete, mostly handles only Fortran 77. User defined types are features of Fortran 90 and very important things were added in Fortran 2003 (OOP, which is relevant when mentioning C++).